# How to create Dnn Text Editor as Rich Editor only?

Tags: dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

I have a Dnn module that contains a Dnn text editor. I want to show that editor on 'Rich' mode only. I try:

```
<dnn:TextEditor runat="server" id="txtUpdate" Width="100%" DefaultMode="RICH" Mode="RICH"></dnn:TextEditor>
```

..but it doesn't work once I set Basic Text Box option.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem... But can't you hide the selector for changing the mode with CSS?

Comment: There is two options or modes to show a DnnText Editor module. I want to know how can I use only the rich editor.